# Правильное использование ограничений в обобщённых типах

Tags: c#, generics

Есть интерфейс IRepository:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : BaseModel {...}
```

где BaseModel- базовый класс для моделей.
Есть провайдер к базе данных, который реализует этот интерфейс:

```
public class Provider<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseModel {...}
```

Есть ли необходимость указывать ограничение на T в случае провайдера, если оно уже указано на уровне интерфейса?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну очень странный вопрос. **Да нужно, потому что без него не компилируется:**

http://ideone.com/zfhSDo

```
public class Provider<T> : IRepository<T> /* where T : BaseModel */ {}
```

> prog.cs(6,14): error CS0314: The type `T' cannot be used as type parameter `T' in the generic type or method `IRepository'. There is no boxing or type parameter conversion from `T' to `BaseModel'
>   prog.cs(5,30): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)

http://ideone.com/I26aUP

```
public class Provider<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseModel {}
```

А тут всё хорошо.

Answer (score 7):

Если ваш вопрос на самом деле: почему ограничения на тип-параметр не наследуются от интерфейса — то [вот](https://ericlippert.com/2013/07/15/why-are-generic-constraints-not-inherited/) ответ на этот вопрос Эрика Липперта, одного из (бывших) разработчиков языка.

Вкратце: потому что в общем случае нету однозначного соответствия параметров класса и параметров интерфейса.

Например, рассмотрим такое объявление:

```
class X<P, Q> where P : ISomething<Q> where Q : Base { }
class Provider<T> : IRepository<X<T, Action<T>>> { }
```

У нас есть констрейнт на `X<T, Action<T>>`, но как превратить его в эффективный констрейнт на `T`, непонятно.